# Where's a Gemfile.apk tutorial? Or the default Gemfile.apk gems?

Tags: ruboto

Ruboto rules like no Android development environment has ruled before. It's like the best of Rails combined with the best of the standard Eclipse-Java-Android environment.

Oh, except it's too new & green to even have tutorials or workarounds or even newbie QA in the forums.

For example, I can install Ruboto, and run it, until I try to add a gem to my application. The instructions seem to say to write a Gemfile.apk text file, and put your gem calls in it.

The problems start when I add a gem to that file:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
gem 'wrong'
```

Then the system starts requesting other gems, such as thor, sqlite3, and Rails. Sometimes, it starts complaining about the versions of sdoc and rdoc. That's a story for another post. The upshot is the system asks for gem files one at a time, and expects specific versions.

This leaves me curious where a "master Gemfile.apk" is. So I can get into it, maybe bundle-install it, and I can stop screwing around with versions & mismatches and s--t.

The versions are ruby 1.9 to 2.1.1, and Ruboto 1.0.3.

Answer (score 2):

A long question with many parts :)  I'll try to cover all, but feel free to file an issue in the Ruboto tracker or ask on the mailing list or on the IRC channel if you need more info ( http://ruboto.org/community.html ).

You can find tutorials here:

https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/wiki/Tutorials-and-examples

You can find the FAQ here:

https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/wiki/FAQ

Tutorials showing use of Gemfile.apk:

- https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Using-Bundler
- https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Using-an-SQLite-database-with-ActiveRecord
- https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/wiki/Tutorial%3A-write-a-gosu-game

There is no "master Gemfile.apk".  Only the gems in the Gemfile.apk and their dependencies should be installed into libs/bundle.jar and included in your app.

I hope this helps you get going.  If you see opportunities for improving the documentation, we are open for contributions.

Comment: Where's the list of gems that Gemfile.apk will pull?

Comment: Those are the documentations that got me into this trouble. And why does bundler demand Rails ??

Comment: You need to show more of what you do.  Ruboto does not require rails in any way.  What command do you use to build your bundle.jar?

Comment: [I will start a new page for this if the problem keeps up]. I add any gem to a new `Gemfile.apk`, run `rake install`, and get a whole bunch of runaway install requests. I will set up a new dev environment and try again